# How can i insert ranges in existing ranges and mix it to new ranges with postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

i try to solve a problem with two lists, and didn't find a working solution for all cases in sql.
I have two tables, a general limit and a special limit. When there is no special limit, i need the general limit, but with a special limit, i need the special limti included to the general.

General limit table

```
Road id | from  | to    | speed
--------+-------+-------+-------
    1   | 12.1  | 88.2  | 100
    2   | 0     | 44.7  | 100
    2   | 44.7  | 88.2  | 50
    2   | 88.2  | 100   | 80
    3   | 13.5  | 100   | 80
    3   | 100   | 124.3 | 85
    3   | 124.3 | 159.2 | 90
```

special limit table

```
road id | vehicle | from | to   | speed 
--------+---------+------+------+-------
    1   |   1     |12.1  |15    | 120
    1   |   2     |14    |17.5  | 140
    2   |   1     |30    |50    | 30
    2   |   2     |0     |20.5  | 40
    3   |   1     |80    |90    | 120
    3   |   1     |100   |110   | 120
    3   |   1     |120   |130   | 120
```

For road=1, vehicle=1 and road=2,vehicle=2 i got it running with

```
with help1 as (select normal.*, null as vehicle from normal
left outer join special on special.fromkm < normal.fromkm and special.tokm > normal.tokm
where normal.roadid=1
union all
select special.roadid,special.fromkm,special.tokm,special.speed,special.vehicle 
from special
where special.vehicle=1 and special.roadid=1
order by fromkm)
,nummer as (select row_number() over (order by fromkm,tokm) as lfdnr,fromkm,tokm,speed
,vehicle from help1 )
select a.lfdnr,
a.fromkm,a.tokm,
case when a.fromkm<c.tokm then c.tokm else a.fromkm end as fromnew,
case when a.tokm>b.fromkm and b.vehicle=null then b.fromkm else a.tokm end as tonew,
a.speed,a.vehicle from nummer a
left join nummer b on a.lfdnr+1=b.lfdnr
left join nummer c on a.lfdnr=c.lfdnr+1
order by fromkm,tokm;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=2019783b0ac7a12f94b8dce45c88a142

```
road id | vehicle | from | to   | speed 
--------+---------+------+------+-------
    1   |   1     | 12.1 |15    | 120
    1   |         | 15   |88.2  | 100

road id | vehicle | from | to   | speed 
--------+---------+------+------+-------
    2   |   2     | 0    |20.5  | 40
    2   |         | 20.5 | 44.7 | 100
    2   |         | 44.7 | 88.2 | 50
    2   |         | 88.2 | 100  | 80
```

But for road=1;vehicle=2, road=2;vehicle=1 and road, it doesn't work, i need to change the "case" expression to solve it
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=23c26e94fe8e7201634ee4593a9631f1

```
road id | vehicle | from | to   | speed 
--------+---------+------+------+-------    
    1   |         | 12.1 | 14   | 100
    1   |   2     | 14   | 17.5 | 140
    1   |         | 17.5 | 88.2 | 100

road id | vehicle | from | to   | speed 
--------+---------+------+------+-------
    2   |         | 0    | 30   | 100
    2   |   1     | 30   | 50   | 30
    2   |         | 50   | 88.2 | 50
    2   |         | 88.2 | 100  | 80
```

And here my special case, when it is inside of one general range. Multiple plus one between two ranges, i don't know how to solve it.

```
road id | vehicle | from | to   | speed 
--------+---------+------+------+-------    
    3   |         | 13.5 | 80   | 80
    3   |   1     | 80   | 90   | 120
    3   |         | 90   | 100  | 80
    3   |   1     | 100  | 110  | 120
    3   |         | 110  | 120  | 85
    3   |   1     | 120  | 130  | 120
    3   |         | 130  | 159.2| 90
```

I need help for the first step to combine case (1,1)(2,2) with (1,2)(2,1) and if it possible a solution for case (3,1)

Comment: Your fiddle good to show what you are getting. But "need the special limit included to the general." Then basically asking a statement "need to change to and from of both lines" - statement ",right ?" - turn into question. Is confusing. Futher it is difficult to say any concerning road,vehicle combinations when neither is identified in the output; and what is lfdnr?  Please post your expected results as formatted text - **no images**

Comment: ok, i changed it, you're right it was not absolutely clear, sorry. lfdnr is a abbreviation of "laufende Nummer" and its the row number, as a helping index